Why does the Torah specify that humankind was created male and female?
For all of the other animals the Torah simply states that they were created. By humankind the Torah specifies that they were created male and female - why?

I heard it in yeshiva from some of the shiurim on family relationships. Geometrically, triangle is a stronger model than a line, which can bend. Building a family out of 3 (man, woman and Hashem) is a stronger construct for building faith, than out of 2 (Adam and Hashem). It is also stated in Koheles 4:9-10:

Two are better off than one, in that they have greater benefit from their earnings. For should they fall, one can raise the other; but woe betide him who is alone and falls with no companion to raise him!


Adam and Eve were first created as a single being, then separated.  The Talmud says:

Rabbi Yirmeya ben Elazar said: The Holy One, Blessed be He, created two faces [du partzufin] on Adam the first man.  He was created both male and female in a single body, as it is stated: “You have formed me [tzartani] back and front” (Psalms 139:5). [Tzartani is derived from the word tzura (face). God formed two faces on a single creation, back and front.] [Berakhot 61a; also Eruvin 18a]

The Midrash echoes this:

Rabbi Shmuel bar Naḥman said: When the Holy One blessed be He created Adam the first man, He created him with two faces, [That is, two conjoined bodies, male and female.] and [subsequently] He sawed him in two [separating the female part from the male part] and made [for] him two backs, [where they had previously been joined together], a back here and a back there... It is as it is stated: “Back [aḥor] and front [kedem] You shaped me…” [Psalms 139:5]
[Genesis Rabbah 8:1]


So if I'm understanding this correctly, the reason why the Torah states He created them male and female is because the first human was literally half male/female?

@Seeker -- Seems to be the case.
